# A box contains four tickets, labeled 0,2,4,10.

Tags: probability, combinatorics

What is the chance that, if you pull 3 tickets out of this box independently, the sum of them is 14?  What I was thinking is

$_4C_3 \cdot (1/4)^3 \cdot 2 = 0.125$.

My logic is we can get a 0, 4, and 10, and the options to choose these is $_4C_3 \cdot (1/4)^3$, but we can also do 2, 2, 10, which is the same probability, thus the times $2$.

Does this look correct?

EDIT: You can replace the tickets.

Thanks!

Bliebervik

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there are only $4$ tickets how can you get $0,2,2,10$?

It looks like the only possibility of getting a sum $14$ is to pull $0, 4, 10$.

In total, you can get $^4C_3=4$ equally probable results, so the probability of pulling a sum $14$ is $\frac{1}{4}$.

Remember that in this example we're counting **subsets**, not sequences.
Maybe I misunderstood something you wrote though.

**EDIT:** If tickets are replaced after each draw, than:

The possible "14-good" outcomes are permutations of $(0, 4, 10)$ and $(2, 2, 10)$. There are $3!$ permutations of the first sequence and $3$ permutations of the second sequence.

There are $4^3$ possible sequences, because on each place (first, second, third) you can choose one of four tickets.

So the probability is $\frac{3!+3}{4^3}=\frac{9}{64}$.

**Remember** - here we're counting **sequences**, not subsets. This is why we have to take all permutations of $(0,4,10)$ and $(2,2,10)$ into consideration and this is why the denominator is the total number of pairwise distinct 3-elements-long sequences with element from the set $\{0, 2, 4, 10\}$

Comment: Sorry - the tickets can be replaced after each draw.

Comment: I edited the answer.

Comment: Why are we counting permutations now? As opposed to combinations?

Comment: Basically because we can. 

*What combinations would you want to count?* If the items pulled can repeat, we're no longer speaking of a subset of a set, because a set by definition doesn't have repeating elements. Think about it.

Comment: That actually doesn't make a lot of sense.  Did you ever have a moment with probability where it just finally clicked? Set theory, number theory... That stuff makes sense to me. This stuff is strange to me.

Comment: I guess I had a really good teacher, so this moment might have been at the very beginning :) Don't worry. Maybe try talking face-to-face to an older friend who you're sure understands it and still remembers what it's like not to understand.

Comment: So combinations are always a subset of a set? I guess that makes sense. Then permutations aren't (well I'm sure they CAN be) if there can be repeating elements?

Comment: When you say "a combination of elements of set $A$" you usually mean "a subset of $A$". When you pull different tickets from a box (without ever putting them back) you're selecting a subset of $A$. On the other hand, when you put the pulled ticket back every time, you construct a sequence made of elements of $A$, but they can repeat, so it's not a subset. In general, when you count subsets the probability is "good subsets" divided by "all possible subsets" (of a certain size in most high school problems). And when you count sequences you divide the no of "good sequences" by no of all of them.

Comment: Thank you sir. That's very very informative.

Comment: You're welcome :) No sir yet, I'm only 18 ;) Good luck in the future.